# How to read DRM protected audio tags in WinRT C#?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, windows-10, taglib

I'm unable to read the tags of the songs downloaded from MixRadio using the inbuilt audio API's of Windows 10 or even using TagLib. The following code is unable to retrieve anything from the file.

```
var test = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
```

TagLib is also failing to get anything. I've noticed that the Groove Music app in Windows 10 is also having the same problem with MixRadio files. Does that mean that there's no way to read these tags? Anyone?

Comment: what's kind of tags, is it possible that these tags are retrieved from the server side?

Comment: I mean audio tags. ID3 tags or any other like Album name, Artist name etc.